# How to test a component in which parameter is being passed to getter from template?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, store

I am writing unit test for one of my component using jest and vue test util. In that component i am using mapGetters to map my store getters and from the template section, i am calling that getter object and passing parameter to it.

/** component.vue **/

```
<v-card-text>{{ message('Jill') }}</v-card-text></v-card>
```

This is how my mapGetters looks like:-

```
computed: {
        ...mapGetters({ message: 'main/message' })}
```

```
/** In the getter.js file **/
message: state => val => setMessage(val)
```

```
function setMessage(val) {
    return `Welcome ${val}.`;
}
```

My question is how would i mock that getter by passing parameter from component's template section ? I tried few ways but i am getting following error:

`'TypeError: _vm.message is not a function'`

Please Help. 
Thanks

Comment: Given that your are trying to call a function from a getter, may I suggest using Vuex actions instead. Furthermore, you will want to define your message as an explicit function, as javascript does not know what is being referenced given that syntax. Lastly, your message function/action should take the string value as an input. ie message:({},payload)=>{return `Welcome ${payload}`}.

Comment: Thanks skyboyer. i will try that.